# Find mysql records from last 3 days

Tags: mysql

I want to get the records for the last 3 days. I have the following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`emails` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`phones` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`history` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`insert_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=259 ;

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `emails`, `phones`, `history`, `insert_date`)
VALUES
(118, 'PLEASE SET',  'addr@yahoo.com', 'None','2015-01-13'),
(237, 'PLEASE SET', 'addr@yahoo.com', 'gomez', '2015-01-11');
```

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), `insert_date`) > 3
```

This gives:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`insert_date`
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: insert_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATE_SUB` expects the second argument to be an `INTERVAL` expression, and will return a date/datetime result, not an integer.

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `insert_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Please note that it is important to compare unmodified `insert_date` value against the calculated date you are comparing against, as this would allow for use of an index on `insert_date`.  You should add this index on your table to optimize the query.

Comment: Is there anyway to optimise this query?

its taking 3 minutes for me to fetch data.

Comment: @AHK Do you have an index on `insert_date`?

Comment: Can you update original question with your new table definition (one in original question does not show index on this column)?  How big is the result set?  How much of the time is spent in querying the data vs. actually transmitting/displaying the data?